# Custom Button Style Content property binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom style for a button

```
 <Style x:Key="CustomButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Width="40" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ****Bind to Content Property on button***}"/>
            </Grid>               
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border>
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="CustomBackground"
                                         Color="LightBlue"/>
                    </Border.Background>

                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>                   
            </ControlTemplate>               
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

with a complex object for my `Content` property.  The value of the `content` property has a `TextBlock`.  Is it possible to bind the `Text` property of the `Textblock` to the `Content` property of the `Button`

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource CustomButton}"
                Content="Bound to Textblock in style"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Use `TemplateBinding` to bind the `TextBlock`'s `Text` to the `Button` `Content`

```
    <Style x:Key="CustomButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="CustomBackground"
                                     Color="LightBlue"/>
                        </Border.Background>

                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Width="40" Height="20" Fill="Yellow"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: When I used your code example I get the following error: `'{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Controls.Control.Template' property on a Setter.`  This is only when I use the `TemplateBinding`.  Also `Content` does not show with intellisense. Only `name`, `uid`, and `ContentStringFormat`

Comment: it works fine at my end !, you did replace the ContentPresenter with the actual content, did yu ?